# renice-like tool for non-root users to increase OOM adjust?

Tags: linux, oom

Is there anything like renice for OOM adjust?  That is, something that would allow a non-root user to increase (but not decrease) the OOM score adjust of processes they own?

Answer (score 1):

We have [choom](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/8fa223daba1963c34cc828075ce6773ff01fafe3) now.

tl;dr:  `choom --adjust -100 myprogram`.

[The man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/choom.1.html) has more information.

Answer (score 0):

There's not anything that does it as a program, but that's when scripting comes in, write a script that finds any PIDs started by their UID, then lets them pick the process, and echoes `-1000` (for example) to `/proc/<pid>/oom_score_adj`.

You can then make it a root only executable, and allow sudo access to the people who need it.

Comment: I'm already doing that.  I'd like to move away from using hand-rolled scripts and sudo authorizations in favor of tools designed for what I want to do.

Comment: About all I can find is something like this.. https://github.com/solarkennedy/oom-tools/blob/master/oom-adjuster.conf it's just one step away from what we're talking about..